# Rails query attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query of pictures like this

```
pictures = Picture.near([latitude, longitude], 6.8).where("created_at >= :time",{:time => time })
```

and i took out the tags which is associated with this model (every picture has_many :tags) like so

```
@tags = Tag.find(:all, :conditions => ["picture_id in (?)",pictures.collect(&:id)])
```

How would I use a query to pull out an attribute of each tag (that is I have an attribute tagcontent for my tags, I need to pull out all of these in activerecord query)

Comment: Something like `@tags.map(&:tagcontent)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer from Alberto Santini's comment.

```
tagcontents = @tags.map(&:tagcontent)
```